# Ignore file with GitHub on windows

Tags: gitignore, github-for-windows

I use [GitHub on windows](https://windows.github.com/), I cloned a wordpress project locally. At the root, the project contains the file **.gitignore** with lines :

```
*.log
wp-config.php
```

So I should not have the wp-config.php file in the root, however **wp-config.php is present** locally.

If I right-click > "Ignores file" on the client: a new line is added to the file .gitignore but my file is not ignored.

Do you know why ?

Thank you !

Comment: Ignore is so that the tools do not consider the file to *add* to the repository. It will not *remove* it if it exists (this is the reason you do this: to have files that you don't want to accidentally add to the repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation for what you are seeing is that the file `wp-config.php` is already being tracked by Git.  Doing `git status` will tell you what is happening.  If the file is already being tracked then you must do the following command *in addition* to adding it to `.gitignore`:

```
git rm --cached wp-config.php
```

Answer (score 1):

from the CLI can you check the status of the `.gitignore` file, with `gitstatus`? Were you able to successfully add, commit and push with the new entry?